# using concat to take first letters from separate words

Tags: php, mysql

My client asked me if i can add to the project, a product code that is generated according to the name of it, and the quantity.
**Per example: if the product is Samsung Grand 2, and the quantity is 30, the code should look like SG2-30.**
My project is written with PHP, MySQL and some JS scripts.

firstly, is this a practical way to code products in stores ?

If yes, how to do it in PHP ?

I tried to concat 2 variables using `concat` but I can't take only the first letter of each word.

```
$query3 = "INSERT INTO inventory
            (item_name, item_code, item_cat, supplier, item_location, quantity, init_price, buy_price, item_sold, date_now) 
            VALUES
            (:item_name, concat(:item_name, :quantity), :item_cat, :supplier, :item_location, :quantity, :init_price, :buy_price, :item_sold, :date)";
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: post your tried code also.

Comment: And the structure of the table, along with some sample data too please.

Comment: Okay, I am doing it wait guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't append quantity to the product identifier.** Quantity is a variable thing and product identifier should be same in all scenarios no matter what the quantity is. If you do it the way you said other problems would rise e.g in searching and indexing etc.

My suggestion is to generate a 5 digit random integer and then apply your scheme you discussed in your question so for example "Samsung Grand 2" will be encoded as something like SG2-12345 and "Samsung Grand 2.1" will be encoded as SG2-98765.

So my answer is `Product initials - 5 digit random number`

Comment: That's it, I will try it now, and see the result

Comment: I tried it and it works, like iPhone Apple 6, I've got IA6-13560

Comment: @androidnation nice to know it helps you

Comment: Instead of a random 5 digit number I would opt for a hash of the product name: `substr(md5('Samsung Grand 2'),0,5)`

Comment: yeah @maxhb its not a bad option .. purpose is to concatenate a 5 digit random string it can be a hash, a random number anything that can serve the purpose

Answer (score 0):

> firstly, is this a practical way to code products in stores ?

Simple answer: No.

This scheme will not prevent ambigious codes. For example "Samsung Grand 2" and "Samsung Grand 2.1" will produce identical encodings (SG2).

Don't use such kind of encoding. Using unique product numbers is a good practice.

Comment: I am totally new to this product coding, is their a link, or a method to learn more about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to get first letters of the string.

```
function get_first_letters($string)
{
  return preg_replace('/(\B.|\s+)/','',$string);
}

$str = 'Samsung Galaxy V 2.1.3';

$first_letters = strtoupper(get_first_letters($str));

echo $first_letters;
```

> Though it is not good practice to create a product code like this.

Comment: Is their any link, about product coding ?

Answer (score 0):

I accept above maxhb's answer but for his solution.

Try the following code.

```
$splitWords = explode(" ", "Samsung Grand 2");
$firstLetters = "";

foreach ($splitWords as $word) {
  $firstLetters .= $word[0];
}
$quantity = 30; //get your quantity from your database

$code = $firstLetters."-".$quantity; //will result SG2-30
```